# Group key-value pairs in chunks no longer than specified limit

Tags: python

Sometime ago I saw a code which packed key,value pairs into several GET messages. That code had a bug (that is why it was shown to me: as the example of beautiful code which doesn't do what it should).

Today I decided to write this code out of curiosity and for training.

This is what I have written:

```
def group(url,D,limit):
    if len(D) == 0:
        if len(url) <= limit:
            yield url
            return
        else:
            raise ValueError("url is longer than limit")

    if len(url) > limit - 2:
        raise ValueError("url is too long to be able to hold any key-value pairs")

    for i,(key,value) in enumerate(D.iteritems()):
        if i == 0:
            old = url
            new = '{url}?{key}={value}'.format(**locals())
            continue
        new, old = '{new}&{key}={value}'.format(**locals()), new

        if len(new) > limit:
            if len(old) > limit:
                raise ValueError("String '{old}' is longer than GET query limit.".format(**locals()))
            yield old
            old = url
            new = '{url}?{key}={value}'.format(**locals())
    if len(new) != len(url):
        if len(new) > limit:
            raise ValueError("String '{new}' is longer than GET query limit.".format(**locals()))
        yield new
```

I have [written some tests](http://ideone.com/VcZzEf) and the code seems to work correctly.

Still, I don't like it.

If we leave alone corner case checking at the beginning, we will only have one working cycle.
Inside that cycle I had to keep two strings: `old` and `new`. If `new` is longer than the limit, I `yield` the old one, and start a new string with blank url plus key,value pair added which caused the previous new string to grow beyond the limit.

To make it work I had to write the same statements in different places of that loop.

For example,

```
old = url
new = '{url}?{key}={value}'.format(**locals())
```

is written it two places.

```
raise ValueError("String '{new}' is longer than GET query limit.".format(**locals()))
```

is also in two places.

Can it be refactored to have statements to be written only once without duplication?

Are there any other things that I should pay attention to?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to return the url if there are no key-value pairs, instead returning without generating any values? It makes the base case different than cases with key-value pairs.

Comment: @ruds I thought about it. And yes, I think it would be more expected behavior. I can implement it this way or that way and describe it in the docstring. But I think if a caller provides empty dictionary, they want just to issue url query with no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def group(url,D,limit):
```

D is a bad parameter name because it doesn't follow the python convention: lowercase_with_underscores, and because it a pointless abbreviation.

```
    if len(D) == 0:
        if len(url) <= limit:
            yield url
            return
        else:
            raise ValueError("url is longer than limit")

    if len(url) > limit - 2:
        raise ValueError("url is too long to be able to hold any key-value pairs")
```

Is this really a useful check? Two characters is probably not enough to actually hold any of the pairs. You probably don't catch anything here you wouldn't already catch

```
    for i,(key,value) in enumerate(D.iteritems()):
        if i == 0:
```

enumerating for the sole purpose of special casing the first entry is rather gross.

```
            old = url
            new = '{url}?{key}={value}'.format(**locals())
            continue
```

I discourage the use of continue. It's almost always better to put things in an else block

```
        new, old = '{new}&{key}={value}'.format(**locals()), new
```

Use of `locals()` is discouraged. It encourages sloppy coding and forces python into a slower compatibility mode for that function.

```
        if len(new) > limit:
            if len(old) > limit:
                raise ValueError("String '{old}' is longer than GET query limit.".format(**locals()))
            yield old
            old = url
            new = '{url}?{key}={value}'.format(**locals())
    if len(new) != len(url):
```

In which case would this be false?

```
        if len(new) > limit:
```

Why is this check inside the other check?

```
            raise ValueError("String '{new}' is longer than GET query limit.".format(**locals()))
        yield new
```

Of course, you've already noted the duplicated code here.

Here's my take on reworking it:

```
def blocked(items, limit, seperator):
    """
    items is a list of strings, to be joined with seperator.
    Produces a generator of strings, each with a length <= the limit
    """
    current = []
    current_length = 0
    for item in items:
        length = len(item) + len(seperator)
        if length > limit:
            raise ValueError('{} cannot fit'.format(item))
        elif length + current_length > limit:
            yield seperator.join(current)
            current = [item]
            current_length = length
        else:
            current.append(item)
            current_length += length
    yield seperator.join(current)

def group(url,data,limit):
    if len(url) > limit:
        raise ValueError('{} is longer than the limit of {}'.format(url, limit))

    pairs = ["{}={}".format(k,v) for k, v in data.iteritems()]
    for block in blocked(pairs, limit - len(url), "&"):
        if block:
            yield '{}?{}'.format(url, block)
        else:
            yield url
```

Comment: Thank you! You pointed to a lot of things I should pay attention to.

Comment: I like your solution where you separated the parameter serialization code into another function `blocked`. This removed code duplication.

Comment: What I would change is `pairs` which can be just generator expression as `blocked` may accept `items` as iterator because it only iterates over these values (no random-access, in-place modifications, etc.)

Comment: I have slightly refactored the code. Made it as lazy as possible. Here is the link: http://ideone.com/81NDnK Maybe it will come in handy for somebody searching for ready solution for this problem.

Comment: @ovgolovin, your pairs generator expression just produces the .iteritems(). You can just pass the return of iteritems into the blocked function. I'm generally suspicious of laziness, as I suspect its usually more expensive if you're going to do the work anyways.